# XML title Regex pattern

Tags: xml, regex, perl

This is my input inside the article the properties will change anything.

**Input:**

```
 <article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:oasis="http://www.niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" article-type="research-article" dtd-version="1.0" xml:lang="en">
```

**Output:**

```
<article article-type="research-article"  xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
```

I try this regex but cant able to do further.

```
<article(?: [^>]+)? article-type="research-article"(?: [^>]+)? xmlns:mml="http://www\.w3\.org/1998/Math/MathML"(?: [^>]+)?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the regex as

```
<article (xmlns:mml=[^ ]*)\s.*(xmlns:xlink=[^ ]*).*(article-type=[^ ]*).*
```

The replacement string can be  `<article $3 $1 $2>`

which gives output as

```
<article article-type="research-article" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

For example see http://regex101.com/r/pX1yI6/1

**EDIT**

if you are unsure about the order in which the property value may occure, its better to use separate matches for each of the properties you wish to extract

For example

```
$str =~ m#(xmlns:mml[^ ]*)#;
$mml=$1;
$str =~ m#(xmlns:xlink[^ ]*)#;
$xlink=$1;
$str =~ m#(article-type[^ ]*)#;
$type=$1;

$output = "<article $type $mml $xlink >";

print $output;
```

will produce output as

```
<article article-type="research-article" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >bash-3.2$ nano xml.pl
```

Comment: it is not a constant properties inside the articel tag it will be swap like this <article xmlns:oasis="http://www.niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" article-type="research-article" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" dtd-version="1.0" xml:lang="en"> so i need from this that three properties. For the above condition it is ok.. If it is random what to do.

Comment: @depsai You mean they are in different order?

Comment: Yes the attributes are in different order @nu11p01n73R

Comment: @depsai In that case you need to have seperate match for each property. I have edited the answer to show that. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @nu11p01n73R i upvote to you. but i need one line regex to do that.

Comment: @depsai i dont think you can have a one liner since the order in which the properties can occure is random

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also: Since the regex pattern could't be jumped to the '<' '>' delimits.

```
print "<$1$2$3$4>\n", if($match=~m{<(article)[^>]*(xmlns:mml="[^"]*")[^>]*(xmlns:xlink="[^"]*")[^>]*(article-type="[^"]*")[^>]*>})
```